# JavaScript replace() not working, get same result

Tags: javascript, regex, string, typescript, replace

I'm trying to get only AN from this string, but replace function seems not working, I end up getting exactly the same string every time... any hits?

```
building = "\n    AN    ";
var temp = building.replace("\\W", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the meta sequence *any non-word character* `\W` and the global flag `g` for a continuing replacement.

```js
var building = "\n    AN    ",
   temp = building.replace(/\W/g, "");
   
console.log(temp);
```